# Extracting and copying data in an excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm extracting data froman excel file that is inside the parameter of the dates provided. But this code is not working. Anybody can help me figure this out?

```
 Set src = wb.Sheets("Request Log Extract")
Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resolution Time Performance")

srcRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
destRow = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
wb.Activate

For i = 2 To srcRow
    If src.Cells("K" & i) >= txtStartDate.Value Or src.Cells("K" & i) <= .txtEndDate.Value Then
        src.Cells("K" & i).Copy
        dest.Activate
        dest.Cells("E" & i).Paste
        src.Activate
    End If

Next
```

This returns an error saying :

> Invalid procedure call or argument.

**NOTE**

txtStartDate and txtEndDate are date Types.

If I use **OR** in the If condition, all data were copied, but if I used **And**, no data is copied. I don't know whats going on.

**VALUES**

txtStartDate 05/13/2016
txtEndDate 05/18/2016
k2 05/14/2016

Comment: Is `srcRow` >= 2? Is `wb` the correct workbook and open? Is `txtStartDate.Value` <= `txtEndDate.Value`? Are you in a correct `With` statement? (`txtEndDate` has a leading point)... Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Couple of thing here. Firstly, `src.Cells("K" & i)` is incorrect. Either use `src.Range("K" & i)` or `src.Cells(i, 11)`where `11` represents column `K`. Secondly, you can paste using `src.Range("K" & i).Copy Destination:=dest.Range("E" & i)`

Comment: @DirkReichel Question is now updated. and wb is already open and active..

Comment: what about that dot before `txtEndDate` ?

Comment: @Mrig I've done what you have suggested, but it seems that even though the values does not match up, they are still copied, and i want also the data only to be copied excluding its cell formats. thanks!

Comment: @Mrig It seems that I have a problem with my if condition. I I replace `or` with `and`, ther's no copied data, but if I replace 1and with `or`, all data were copied. I just want to copy the data that is between the two.

Comment: I'll need few clarifications here. What are the values of `txtStartDate` and `txtEndDate`. In `IF` condition you have `OR`, that means whatever value from `Request Log Extract` sheet you are checking in `IF` condition, that value should be `greater than txtStartDate` and `smaller than txtEndDate` i.e that value should not fall between `txtStartDate` and`txtEndDate`.

Comment: To check date between two dates, you'll have to use `AND` in `IF` condition.

Comment: Can you show the values of `txtStartDate`, `txtEndDate` and `K2` value of `Request Log Extract` sheet.

Comment: You can see these values by writing: `Debug.Print txtStartDate.Value`, `Debug.Print txtEndDate.Value` and `Debug.Print src.Range("K2").Value` in the code.

Comment: @Mrig Updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure with your txtStartDate and txtEndDate variables, but look at my code
I declared your variables, but please specify date types, also i removed dot from `txtEndDate` and changed cell references and now it works.

```
Sub extractData()
Dim src
Dim dest
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim txtStartDate
Dim txtEndDate

Set src = wb.Sheets("Request Log Extract")
Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resolution Time Performance")

srcRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
destRow = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

txtStartDate = 0
txtEndDate = 100

For i = 2 To srcRow
    If src.Cells(i, "K").Value > txtStartDate Or src.Cells(i, "K").Value < txtEndDate Then
        src.Cells(i, "K").Copy
        dest.Activate
        dest.Cells(i, "E").PasteSpecial
        src.Activate
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a date value issue

Moreover I'm guessing your code is within some userform pane and activated at some button click after which it has to compare two textboxes values to some cells content and copy/paste values accordingly

should my guessing be right (finger crossed...) try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim src As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
    Dim srcRow As Long, destRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date, cellDate As Date

    With Me
        If Not ValidateDate("txtStartDate", .txtStartDate.Value, startDate) Then Exit Sub
        If Not ValidateDate("txtEndDate", .txtEndDate.Value, endDate) Then Exit Sub

        Set src = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Request Log Extract") '<~~ change workbook reference as per your need
        Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resolution Time Performance")
        srcRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
        destRow = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For i = 2 To srcRow
            If ValidateDate("src.Range(""K" & i & """)", src.Range("K" & i), cellDate) Then
                If cellDate >= startDate And cellDate <= endDate Then src.Range("K" & i).Copy dest.Range("E" & i)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub


Function ValidateDate(textName As String, textValue As String, retDate As Date) As Boolean
    ValidateDate = IsDate(textValue)
    If ValidateDate Then
        retDate = DateValue(textValue)
    Else
        MsgBox textValue & " is not a valid date" & vbCrLf & "please input a new value for " & textName
    End If
End Function
```

should my guessing be wrong, still the code above can give you some suggestions as to the date value issue

Comment: @kruk22 this code is "UserForm-ready". There should be not much to study about but inserting it properly in your UserForm event handler

Comment: have you gone through your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim txtStartDate As Date, txtEndDate As Date

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set src = wb.Sheets("Request Log Extract")
    Set dest = wb.Sheets("Resolution Time Performance")

    srcRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    destRow = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    txtStartDate = "05/13/2016"
    txtEndDate = "05/18/2016"

    For i = 2 To srcRow
        If src.Range("K" & i).Value >= txtStartDate And src.Range("K" & i).Value <= txtEndDate Then
            src.Range("K" & i).Copy Destination:=dest.Range("E" & i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @kruk22 have you tried my answer code? which I actually wrote _guessing_ it should be in a UserForm environment

Comment: I've got the problem now. It seems that my code is not able to get the value in my text box in UForm.

Comment: @kruk22 don't understand if you speaking about my code

Comment: @kruk22 - I tried your code using UserForm and it is working for me. Just remove `.` from `.txtEndDate.Value` in `IF` condition.

Comment: @user3598756 Im sorry, I'm referring to mine. heheh .. Haven't tried well your code, I'm still studying your code .

Comment: if I remove it, asks for the `then` keyword, so can't proceed

Comment: I dont have any `WITH` statement. Thanks!

Comment: Then I think it will be better if you can share your file. You can remove the confidential data.